# How could I compute the number of $i$-cycle in $A_5$, with $i \in \{3,5\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How could I compute the number of $i$-cycle in $A_5$, with $i \in \{3,5\}$?

I thought that the number of $3$-cycle was $C(5,3)/5$, but it is not good.

Is anyone is able to explain to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p$ odd, the number of $p$-cycle in $A_{n}$ is the same as in the mother group $S_{n}$, which is given by $(p -1)! \binom{n}{p}$. In your particular case you get $20$ and $24$.